# Printing a byte from an unsigned integer in C

Tags: c, byte, unsigned-integer

I am new to C and I have a question regarding a problem I have.
I need to get this input:
 AA
BB
CC
DD

But I get this all time AA
BB
CC00
DD

The code I am using is :

```
int main(void) {

 unsigned int   getal,temp;
        printf("Voer een getal in: \n");
        scanf("%0X",&getal);
        temp = getal & 0xFF000000;
        temp=temp>>24;

        printf("%0X\n", temp);
        temp = getal & 0xFF0000;
        temp=temp>>0xFF0;

        printf("%0X\n", temp);
        temp = getal & 0xFF00;
        temp=temp>>0xFF0000;

        printf("%0X\n", temp);
        temp = getal & 0xFF;
        printf("%0X\n", temp);

        return 0;

}
```

I appreciate all the help I can get!

Comment: those shifts look odd. I expected to see >> 0, >> 8, >> 16 and >> 24

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean `temp >> 24`, `temp >> 16`, and `temp >> 8`. Weird, you got the first one right, why did you suddenly do something totally different?